# Puertos de router no se abren

Tags: router, puertos

Estoy tratando de abrir los puertos del router DPQ3925 haciendo un forwarding hacia un host interno. Sin embargo estos no se abren. Tampoco funciona el acceso remoto a pesar de estar activado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué podría estar pasando? Ya le pasé el nmap y los puertos siguen cerrados.

Comment: ¿Cómo está conectado tu router a internet? ¿Puede ser que tenga un MODEM que esté configurado como router? Si es así prueba cambiándolo a gateway.
Suerte!

Comment: Intenta siguiendo esta guia: https://portforward.com/cisco/dpq3925/

Comment: Sólo por descartar: - ¿Has escaneado el host de destino ( 192.168.0.12 ) para comprobar que tienes los puertos 32306 y 32316 a la escucha? Mis 2¢

Comment: Pues si , lo he escaneado con nmap , pero solo esta abierto 1 , es un host con windows ,ya he puesto reglas en el firewall , hasta lo he desactivado y  sigue sin reconocer los 2 , por ahi lei que nmap lo reconoce como filtrado si esque no esta en uso el puerto.

Comment: Una vez tuve un problema similar, se ve que el router no era muy bueno y solo me funciono modificando el DMZ, lo que no recuerdo es si para que funcione lo deje Enable o Disable, podrías probar con ambas configuraciones para ver si seguis teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: buenas tardes: Antes que nada necesitaría mas datos, primero: * ¿Tienes Dmz activado a la ip de tu servidor/PC? * ¿La Pc tiene activado la conexión a escritorio remoto con sus respectivos permisos? * ¿Que SO tiene el servidor/PC? * ¿ Proveedor tuyo de Internet?, a que Ip estas intentando conectarte por ej: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX:32316 ? Como haces para conectarte remotamente? te conectas desde afuera? a a través de una vpn? o directamente apuntas a la ip publica? Espero tu respuesta! Muchas gracias Un abrazo!

Comment: Hola el DMZ lo active , el pc al que quiero conectarme tiene windows 7 con firewall desactivado , aun asi en una laptop con gentoo configurando iptables no me mapea los puertos ,el proveedor es claro  a la ip que estoy tratando de conectarme es 179.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 (acceso remoto) para entrar a la configracion del router ,el proveedor es claro , trato de conectarme directamente , y no si si tal vez sea porque me han asignado nat3.

Comment: Viendo los logs me sale el siguiente mensaje Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC=cc:0d:ec:c2:92:60;CMTS-MAC=00:30:b8:cc:b0:02;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Comment: En otro lugar me dicen que no podré hacer la coneccion remota porque tengo nat3.

Comment: Por si te sirve, a mí la conexión remota a través de la IP pública no me funcionaba, pensaba también que mi router no funcionaba bien, a pesar de haberle configurado el port forwarding. Pero probé desde un equipo fuera de la red local, y entonces me di cuenta de que funcionaba perfectamente. Por tanto, cuando quiero conectarme desde un equipo de la red local, uso la IP local, y cuando es desde fuera (Internet) uso la IP pública.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no se resuelve en SOes

Answer (score 0):

Activa el `DMZ` de tu router y coloca la IP a la que va a apuntar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola ya hice como pusiste , pero aun asi sigue cerrado ,lo peor es que el acceso remoto no funciona ,ademas no se supone que 0.0.0.0 es paratodos los hosts?

Comment: funcionaba antes el acceso remoto? 0.0.0.0 es que no está configurado

Comment: es la primera vez que trato de abrir el acceso remoto en este router asi como los puertos , pero que raro ya desactive todos los firewalls , y he hecho como los tutoriales , pero me los detecta como cerrados con el nmap,asi como otras herramientas para testear puertos.

Comment: has intentado seguir la guía que publicó @Juan Pinzón como comentario a tu pregunta?

Comment: si ya lo intente fredyfx

Comment: Te has planteado que el problema no sea el router y que sea el ordenador destino el que este tirando la conexión?

Comment: puede ser , pero son 2 problemas ,  1 para mapear los puertos , y 2 el acceso remoto , esto ultimo deberia funcionar , pero ni siquiera puede tener acceso al router desde un ordenador externo , estando habilitado las opciones y desactivado el firewall del router.